# Place color and text on top of a word in a div in css to hide it and on click show the hidden text

Tags: javascript, css

I want to show on top of this div, a color and a text saying "click here" in order to hide all letters of word HIDETHIS except the two last letters. Then on click i want the color and text to disappear and the word HIDETHIS to become visible to the user.

```
<div id="copy-target" align="center" style="border: 3px dashed #ccc;background-color:transparent;color:black;margin:5px;font-weight:700;"> HIDETHIS</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the word in two elements like so `<span class="toBeHidden">HIDETH</span>IS`, then you can use js to remove the color/text (that could be another element inside the `.toBeHidden` span).
`<span class="toBeHidden">HIDETH<span class="overlay">CLICK HERE</span></span>IS`
and something like this for the CSS:

```
.toBeHidden{
  position: relative;
}
.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
 }
```